# Remove certain words from website using JS

Tags: javascript, replace, web, blogs

What Javascript code can be used to remove certain words from a website? I'd like this to be done on the client side, additionally.

Comment: You can't.  Not reliably, anyway.  There will *always* be some way around it.

Comment: Sure you can. Is it a best practice? No.

Comment: you should use client-side validation on anything a user can input. check against a list of badwords in all languages used by your users. I'd rather do that server-side as it could be intensive on big sites. there is no perfect solution though. LOOK AT MY A$$!

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Humans will *easily* find ways around every filter you can possibly design.  Particularly when all the filtering is client-side, and the offensiveness is in the ideas and words rather than in the characters.  The truth of it is, anyone considering software means of filtering "bad words" to any useful degree, is staring down a *very* deep rabbit hole.  This is really a job for humans, not computers.

Comment: So what? Anybody can type in an offensive word in the address bar or say it out loud too. This is such an insignificant filter that's being taken way too seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var el = document.body;
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/badword|anotherone|andanother/gi, '***');
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Lweebyqv/

Comment: Cl\*\*\*ic first attempt.   But it won't quite p\*\*\* muster if the RE contains, say, `ass`.  :P

Comment: Not to mention, it opens up the possibility for the words to be snuck in.  Let's say you replace `/ass|dick/`.  What happens when you run into "diassck"?  After the replacement, you get "di\*\*\*ck".

Comment: instead of adding a space before each pipe, why not make the actual swears a capture group and add a space before the capture group? It should really check if a space exists before OR after the statement, and if either triggers then the statement should be true, but it's a good start anyways.

Comment: @tomysshadow: Wouldn't catch *\*badword\**.  Which is a pretty important one to find, considering the stars are a commonly used method of emphasis.

Comment: going by that logic, Cl***ic would be filtered again though. Perhaps checking for symbols and spaces??

Comment: @tomysshadow: Note how what we have to check for is starting to grow?  It'll keep on doing that til it consumes you.  This is a much harder problem than a couple of lines of code can reasonably solve.

Comment: I don't think so, Procon Latte does it perfectly well

Comment: You guys are taking this way too seriously

Comment: No, you're not taking it seriously enough.  If these words are inappropriate enough to justify scrubbing, then it shouldn't be trivial to make them appear.  Your answer being broken is just evidence that it's more complicated than it looks.

Comment: Google "clbuttic" or "Scunthorpe problem" for more info.

Comment: I personally think no words are inappropriate enough to justify scrubbing.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: I tend to agree.  (Which might not be much of a shocker. :))  But that's basically what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Maybe, but pretty much the only people who probably shouldn't see inappropriate words are little kids, who shouldn't be on a website that could potentially display bad words and should have parent moderation, and also most likely aren't savvy enough to open up the chrome console and hack stuff. That's why I'm not taking it seriously.

Comment: I use Disqus for comments, and that's where I get the words. Does the method shown by @AlienWebguy work for async elements and Disqus? (I know Disqus may have a place to input bad words to go, where is that?) Also:

Comment: Also, my site has a Tumblr blog connected. We get hundreds of reblogs, but for some reason, all the reblogs and likes show up and everybody's username is all like **** (bad words).

Comment: This method still working for me in 2023 as a userscript.